# ASP.NET MVC Global.asax Shared Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it alright to hang a shared property off of the global.asax (MvcApplication class)?

And then access it like so in other area:

`MvcApplication.[SharedPropertyName]`

**Edit**

What I am trying to do is have a globally accessible property that is my application settings.

I am using an `XmlSerializer` to serialize/deserialize an object that holds all of these properties. It works great, but the `Load` method on the `ApplicationSettings` is shared and returns an instance of the `ApplicationSettings`, so some of the other ideas people have suggested around singelton is not going to work. Here is the `ApplicationSettings` class:

```
Public Class ApplicationSettings

#Region "Members/Properties"

    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    ...

#End Region

#Region "Methods"

    Public Shared Function GetFilePath() As String
        Return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Bin/Settings.config")
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Load() As ApplicationSettings
        Try
            Dim Serializer As XmlSerializer
            Dim Settings As ApplicationSettings

            Using Reader As New StreamReader(GetFilePath)
                Serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ApplicationSettings))
                Settings = CType(Serializer.Deserialize(Reader), ApplicationSettings)
                Reader.Close()
            End Using

            Return Settings

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Return New ApplicationSettings
            Return Nothing

        End Try

    End Function

    Public Sub Save()
        Dim Serializer As XmlSerializer

        Using Writer As New StreamWriter(GetFilePath, False)
            Serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ApplicationSettings))
            Serializer.Serialize(Writer, Me)
            Writer.Flush()
            Writer.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not recommended.  If you need a globally accessible variable or property, that's more suited to a base class that your classes inherit from.

[This link](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/18/asp-net-mvc-tip-4-create-a-custom-data-controller-base-class.aspx) gives an example of a controller base class.

**EDIT:**

Based off your edit, it's tough to recommend something specific because how those settings are used can drive your approach.  Here's some general tips:

1. I'd split out your settings into a series of base classes that are distinct in their area of concern.  So settings regarding FunctionalityX lives within the class dealing with FunctionalityX.
2. I'd leverage your web.config.  I'm sure you're already doing this, but just make sure that you're not duplicating configuration efforts.  The Web.Config is the right place for most of it and you can add more.  Classes already exist for pulling configuration information out of the web config.

Alright, with that having been said, barring those two paths:

1. I'd set your class to static so you can just reference your class from anywhere without instantiation like this: `ApplicationSettings.SettingValue`.
2. I'd have explicit settings properties on your ApplicationSettings class and reference them directly that way.  If they aren't instantiated, you can lazy load them from the XML as they are needed.
3. I'd cache your settings if they aren't dynamic.

So there's some general tips that might yield a better solution.  It's hard to recommend something concrete without further information on how it'll be used.

**FINAL EDIT:**

After some discussion in the comments below, we found that this resource here fixed the OP's issue:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx

Comment: I am not using the web.config, because the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` wants a string for the key name. With my solution, it is all strongly typed. In the Application_Start of the global.asax, it reads this config file into `ApplicationSettings`, so they are cached for the life of the app. What I was originally trying to do was have a class, say `AppSettings` that had an exact duplicate of the `ApplicationSettings` class properties, but that were static, and then use AutoMapper to map the ApplicationSettings loaded from the file to the AppSettings static properties. Any ideas?

Comment: Well I have no choice but to circumvent your question and to instead try and solve your initial problem that led you astray!  You **can** reference your web.config in a strongly-typed fashion.  Would that eliminate your need for this custom configuration implementation?  http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx  This solution seems to be pretty much what you're getting at.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll edit my original answer post.  Please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. There likely is a better way to do what you are attempting to do.